# How to flatten multi dimensional object which is in fact array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

So, i have multi dimensional - multi object array which looks something like this(just a snippet):

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Justimmo\Model\Realty)#14 (136) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    int(103xxx757)
    ["propertyNumber":protected]=>
    string(10) "3108xx6"
    ["title":protected]=>
    string(62) "Ruhige 3-Zimmer mit Freifläche in ..."
    ["teaser":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["proximity":protected]=>
    string(4) "Wien"
    ["description":protected]=>
    ["additionalCosts":protected]=>
       array(1) {
         ["betriebskosten"]=>
         object(Justimmo\Model\AdditionalCosts)#24 (8) {
           ["name":protected]=>
           string(14) "Betriebskosten"
           ["net":protected]=>
           float(140)
           ["gross":protected]=>
           float(154)
           ["vat":protected]=>
           float(10)
           ["vatType":protected]=>
           string(7) "percent"
           ["vatValue":protected]=>
           float(14)
           ["vatInput":protected]=>
           float(10)
           ["optional":protected]=>
           bool(false)
        }
    }
...........
```

How can i flatten it to be one dimensional array so i can process it further?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "flatten", and what do you mean by "process it further"? Perhaps you could [edit] the question to show an example of what you want? Also, note that the properties shown are marked "protected", meaning they're only accessible *inside* the object; presumably the object is intended to be interacted with via methods, not by looking at the data directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
function flatten_all($obj){
    $array = array();
    foreach( $obj as $key => $value ){
        if( is_object($value) || is_array($value) ){
            $temp_array = flatten_all((array)($value));
            foreach( $temp_array as $t_key => $t_value ){
                $array[$t_key] = $t_value;
            }
        }
        else{
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much! now i have another problem. i get malformed data.
array(198) {
  ["^@*^@id"]=>
  int(16399196)
  ["^@*^@propertyNumber"]=>
  string(10) "3108880086"
  ["^@*^@title"]=>
  NULL
  ["^@*^@teaser"]=>
  NULL
  ["^@*^@proximity"]=>